# barcode scanner sample cannot be killed

Tags: windows-ce, motorola-emdk

When I launch a CS_Barcode2Sample1 sample (from Motorola EMDK for .NET v2.6 or 2.5) on a device (Motorola WT4090 or MC9090) and immediately, without doing any scanning, try to kill it it won't go away. Only warm-booting will get rid of it. Couple of background threads hanging there seem to be related to scanner having been enabled in the application.

This same behavior happens in my application, which prevents me from being able to do automatic upgrades.

I wonder if anyone else experienced the problem and was able to resolve it.

Comment: Does CS_BarcodeSample1 work?  Though the specific details escape me, I remember having issues with Barcode2 that did not occur with Barcode (which is what we ended up deploying on our MC3090s).

Comment: Current app uses code for Barcode and it's the same thing. I'm leaning towards using synchronous reads using my own thread. With Barcode2 you can call ScanWait with timeout specified. During those timeouts if the process was killed in the meantime scanner threads are discarded as well (they're probably not there to begin with, because of the timeout). Their implementation of the "async" read seems far from being stellar.